# IE11 Object doesn't support property or method 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)_a.2p3bca3ct9h

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer, babel-polyfill

I am using `Angular 8, tslint 5.15 & typescript v3`

I am reading file as `ArryaBuffer` using below code

```
const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(<FileObject>);
    reader.onload = () => {
      this.uploadedData= new Uint8Array(reader.result as ArrayBuffer);
    }
```

Now when i pass this `uploadedData` into API, I am converting into byteArray using below fucntion.

```
convertLicenseToByteArray(uploadedData) {
    const bytesArray = [];
    for (const i of uploadedData) {
      bytesArray.push(i);
    }
    return bytesArray;
  }
```

The above code is giving error in ie11,

> ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method
>   'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)_a.srxqdvyfxlx'

I tried to search on net and found that may be i need to add `babel-polyfill` but it's not working for me.

Any help?

Comment: console.log your `uploadedData` and see if `Symbol(Symbol.iterator)` is present in the `object prototype`. If not it's `not iterable` data structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add '`core-js`' into you package.json and add import into your `polyfills.ts`

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
```

Comment: I tried what you suggest, But still got the same error!

Comment: I followed https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4075#issuecomment-321466247
Which looks similar to your answer, And i believe it should work. But no luck!

Comment: Things started working on new year with this solution :)
Happy New Year in true sense!

Comment: So, how's your year been?

Answer (score 2):

IE11 doesn't support virtually any of ES2015+, so that means no arrow functions, no Symbol, and no iterables and iterators. (IE9-IE11 do support `const` and `let`, but not properly. They support an early version that isn't what was standardized. The biggest discrepancy is in regard to `for` loops.)

If you want to run that code on IE11, you'll need to transpile it to ES5 and add some polyfills. Symbol and iterability can't be properly polyfilled, but [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and others provide *something* partially functional. I see [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) that Babel now recommends **not** using their own `@babel/polyfill` and instead using [`core-js`](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) directly (and [regenerator runtime](https://github.com/facebook/regenerator/blob/master/packages/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js) if you need to transpile generator functions).

Comment: Crowder, Your answer is also correct and the explanation is also good. But the accepted answer saved my time ;)

Comment: It's my pleasure to talk with such a decent person (Author of "JavaScript The new 
 Toys" book)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is relates to the uploadedData parameter, when we call the convertLicenseToByteArray method and use the uploadedData variable, if the data is not populated or undefined, it will display this error.

You could try to call the convertLicenseToByteArray method in the reader onload function.

```
  const reader = new FileReader();    
  reader.onload = (_event) => { 
    this.uploadedData= new Uint8Array(reader.result as ArrayBuffer);   
    console.log(this.convertLicenseToByteArray(this.uploadedData).length);
  }
```

Comment: But in my case, it's not undefined

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that might be having this problem in an Aurelia project without typescript, I was able to solve it by installing core-js which included the polyfills needed to make this work.

`npm install --save core-js@3.6.5`

I then added the import in the .js file where I was having the issue and it started working.

`import "core-js"`